# get items from checkboxlist and insert comma between its items

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist and want to when I select some items ,insert ',' between items,e.g select IDs 123 and will become 1,2,3.

```
 protected string addcomma(string[] stuff)
    {
        string s;
        foreach (string  i in stuff)
        {
            s += Items;
            s += ',';
        }
        return s;
    }
```

and:

```
string limit = addcomma( (CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue));
```

I am not sure . What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] selectedItems = myCheckboxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                       .Where(o => o.Selected)
                                       .Select(o => o.Value)
                                       .ToArray();
string limit = string.Join(",", selectedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is partially correct.

`CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue` returns the first selected value and not all the selected values of the `CheckBoxList1` object.
Your `addcomma` method should be like:

```
protected string addcomma(List<string> stuff)
{
    string s="";
    foreach (string i in stuff)
    {
        s += i;
        s += ',';
    }
    return s;
}
```

Note that your last character of the `s` string will always be a comma.

You should use it like:

```
    List<string> selectedValues = new List<string>();

    foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
        {
            selectedValues.Add(li.Value);
        }
    }
    string limit = addcomma(selectedValues);
```

PS. I am using a list because we don't know how many items are selected.